# BindingMethods for overloaded methods?

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

Say I have methods like

```
setImageTintList(ColorStateList)
```

and

```
setImageTintList(ColorStateList, boolean)
```

Normally I would set binding methods like

```
@BindingMethods({
   @BindingMethod(type = "android.widget.ImageView",
                  attribute = "android:tint",
                  method = "setImageTintList"),
})
```

How would I do the same for `setImageTintList(ColorStateList, boolean)`?

NOTE: The methods I mentioned are just for setting an example, taken from the documentation.